# Logging value in array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm confused about how to get a value out of the row2 array below. When I log the full array, as I've done in the code, I see all nine values listed that come from row two of the spreadsheet. However when I try to pull out the 9th value, also listed in the code, the result is undefined. Can anyone tell me why?

```js
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // get the spreadsheet object
var reportConfig = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Report Configuration"); // set report configuration sheet
var lastColumn = reportConfig.getLastColumn();
var lastColumnTitle = reportConfig.getRange(1,lastColumn).getValue();
var row2 = reportConfig.getRange(2,1,1,lastColumn).getValues();
Logger.log(row2);
Logger.log(row2[9]);
```

Comment: Arrays are indexed starting from 0, position 9 is row[8]

Comment: Yes, that's right. I made a typo in the code. I am getting a result of undefined with
    Logger.log(row2[8])

Comment: Oooops, answer below is right indeed... didn't notice the getValues in your code. Sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

row2 will be a 2D-array, so row2[9] would refer to the 10th row in that array which doesn't exist.
try: Logger.log(row2[0][9])

or change row2 to 
var row2 = reportConfig.getRange(2,1,1,lastColumn).getValues()[0]

and then do:
Logger.log(row2[9])

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I'm confused why it's a two-dimensional array though. If I'm using only one row of data, shouldn't it be a one-dimensional array? I appreciate the help.

Comment: .getValues() always returns a 2D-array, even for just one row.. But glad to hear the issue is solved !